# How to caryy out a git command without giving control to the interactive the git console?

Tags: powershell, git

I am new to Git, first time I am using it.

I installed it, in my "program files" folder there two executables there:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe
C:\Program Files\Git\git-cmd.exe
```

Just to confirm things are in working order, I managed to clone a repository to a local folder using `git-cmd`, by directly executing it in File Explorer, then in that new cmd window:

```
cd "c:\temp"
git clone https://github.com/SomeName/SomeRepo
```

Of course I would like to do this in my PowerShell envoiroment in Windows Terminal. I have tried:

```
. "C:\Program Files\Git\git-cmd.exe" clone "https://github.com/SomeName/SomeRepo"
```

All that happens is some CMD window flashes, closes, then my PowerShell prompt is replaced with what looks to be a CMD style promt.

I am looking to stay inside my powershell envoiroment and simply carry out a single "Git" command, clone the repo to the current directory.

I also tried this with `git-bash`, this opens its own window:

```
.  "C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe" clone https://github.com/SomeName/SomeRepo
```

I tried using the comd flag `/c` with `git-cmd`, no luck:

```
. "C:\Program Files\Git\git-cmd.exe" /c clone "https://github.com/SomeName/SomeRepo"
```

I was not expecting to go down a rabbit hole at this late hour, please send help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of these executables is Git. `git.exe` is in the `bin` folder.

`git-bash.exe` is a utility to launch *Git Bash*, a minimal UNIX-y environment with a Bash shell preconfigured to use Git, with tab completion and branch names in the prompt and whatnot.

`git-cmd.exe` is somewhat similar, but launches a standard Windows Command Prompt instead. This is useful because you can decide to not have `git.exe` in `%PATH%`, making these special shell launchers your only option. (Using the full path is also always possible.)

If you did decide to have Git in `%PATH%` when you installed it, you do not need to worry about where `git.exe` is. Just use Git commands.

Plain `git.exe` is also fine for use in PowerShell. Posh-Git is *not* required.

Comment: That is what I was missing. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Git inside of PowerShell, you will need to install posh-git. The following options came from
[A1.8 Appendix A: Git in Other Environments - Git in PowerShell](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Appendix-A%3A-Git-in-Other-Environments-Git-in-PowerShell)

**Option 1 - Installing posh-git via Chocolatey**

- First [install Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/install)
- `choco install poshgit`

**Option 2 - Installing From PowerShell Gallery**

If you have at least PowerShell 5 or PowerShell 4 with PackageManagement installed, you can use the package manager to install posh-git for you.

- Set the value of `ExecutionPolicy` to `RemoteSigned` for all users use
  the next command:
- `> Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope LocalMachine -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force`
- `> Install-Module posh-git -Scope CurrentUser -Force`
- `> Import-Module posh-git`
- `> Add-PoshGitToProfile -AllHosts`

**Option 3 - Installing from Source**

- Set the value of `ExecutionPolicy` to `RemoteSigned` for all users use
  the next command:
- `> Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope LocalMachine -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force`
- Download a posh-git release from
  https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/releases, and uncompress it. Then
  import the module using the full path to the posh-git.psd1 file:
- `> Import-Module <path-to-uncompress-folder>\src\posh-git.psd1`
- `> Add-PoshGitToProfile -AllHosts`
- This will add the proper line to your profile.ps1 file, and posh-git will be active the next time you open PowerShell.